# Posting to API via zapier code and getting this error

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, javascript-objects, zapier

I am trying to run a JSON post to an API I am working with Via Zapier Code.

I have defined my inputs and this is my code below. It seems to get through most of it without any syntax errors. But Zapier is now giving me this error response and I cannot figure out why?

"We had trouble sending your test through. Please try again. Error: 
You must return a single object or array of objects."

Does anyone have any input on this?

```js
const API_URL = "https://myapi.com";

const DATA = {
  siteId: "xxxx",
  id: inputData.orderId,
  totalATI: 39.99,
  totalET: 39.99,
  currency: "USD",
  accountId: inputData.accountId,
  ip: inputData.userIP,
  recoverUrl: "",
  civility: "",
  lastname: inputData.lastname,
  firstname: inputData.firstname,
  email: inputData.accountId,
  homePhoneNumber: "",
  mobilePhoneNumber: "",
  phoneNumber: inputData.userPhone,
  countryCode: "01",
  custom:{},
  
  items: [{
  id: "88",
  label: "CR",
  quantity: 1,
  totalATI: 39.99,
  totalET: 39.99,
  url: "https://myurl.com",
  imageUrl: "https://myimage.com",
  universe: "",
  category:  ""
  }]
};

fetch(API_URL, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'X-API-Key': 'xxx'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(DATA)
}).then(function(res){
  return res.json();
}).then(function(response){
  // API response
  if(response.success){
    // Tell zapier success
    callback(null, {
      result: "success",
      message: "Request successful!",
      data: response
    });
  }
  // Some error happened.
 else {callback(response)};

}).catch(callback);
```

Comment: I'm not sure what else is wrong, but immediately what jumps out is the `return` after the successful callback (you don't need it) and the extra param in the failure callback (should be `else {callback(response)}`. If you change those two things and it doesn't work, let me know and i can take a closer look!

Comment: Hey @xavdid,

I changed both of those things to my callback response.  

Unfortunately, I am still getting the same error "You must return a single object or array of objects."  

Could it be something with the way the DATA object is structured?

Comment: can you update your question with the newer code so we're on the same page? `DATA` shouldn't be a problem since it doesn't have to do with what's returned from the function. Maybe the issue is a dropped promise? hard to say without knowing what the service returns. try adding `.catch(callback)` to the end of the promise chain. it would be good to know what logic branch you're in.

Comment: I updated the code with your suggestions.  The problem with Code by Zapier .. is as far as i'm aware, it doesn't give you back the catch.  You only get Zapiers error response.

Comment: Ah, i'm sorry. put the `catch` at the very end of the code, before the final semi-colon. that'll catch anything bad happening in any of the calls. Example here: https://zapier.com/help/code/#weather-json-api-call

Comment: I think the promise will fail (have a >=400 response code) instead of having `response.success` be false (with a 200 response code). that depends on the external service, but it's a common pattern

Comment: We had trouble sending your test through. Please try again. Error: 
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
Object.parse (native)
  /var/task/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/body.js:43:15
  process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)

Comment: hard to say. I'd spend some time debugging in the chrome console. You'll have to define `inputData` manually (it's just an object) but it has access to the same fetch and stuff. My guess is it's also broken there, but it'll give you better error info.

Comment: Ok Thanks, it actually seems like my code is working to pass the info to the API, (I just confirmed with there tech support) ...  but for some reason, Zapier keeps throwing the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what is happening here is that the response from the API is not a proper JSON which is why the call is being made to the API but the `fetch` library is unable to parse the response.

For example, this piece of code is to parse a JSON response.

```
fetch(API_URL, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(DATA),
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'X-API-Key': 'xxx'
    }
})
    .then(function(res) {
        return res.json();
    })
    .then(function(body) {
        console.log(body);
        callback(null, body.json);
    }).catch(callback);
```

This code will error out when the response is NOT a proper JSON.

You could try changing your code to the following where you are considering the response to be in text.

```
fetch(API_URL, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(DATA),
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'X-API-Key': 'xxx'
    }
})
    .then(function(res) {
        return res.text();
    })
    .then(function(body) {
        console.log(body);
        var output = {rawHTML: body};
        callback(null, output);
    })
    .catch(callback);
```

I've posted a similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49954171/zapier-javascript-to-webhook-post/49962300#49962300).